# Is there a simpler and efficient way to store n space delimited values in n different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

```
i,j,k = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
a.append(i)
b.append(j)
c.append(k)
```

The above code works fine but can we write this code in a simpler and efficient way?
I am looping through n lines having three integers in each line and want to create three separate lists for 1st value, 2nd value, and 3rd value from each line.

> In English I want to do something like:
>
> a.append(x) , b.append(y) where x , y in
>   sys.stdin.readline().split()

as a result, I want to read a line and append the values in a separate list so when I access list a[] it contains the first value of each line

```
Input:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12


Output:
a
>> [1, 4, 7, 10]
b
>> [2, 5, 8, 11]
c
>> [3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Comment: Are you going to be reading many such lines?

Comment: Please show a [mre] of your full problem or explain better. You are saying "having 3 integers in each line" but showing a read of just one line

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for many lines, you can unpack a generator that converts *all* your lines as arguments to `zip`, which will then produce a `tuple` of the first elements of each line, then a `tuple` of the elements of the second line, etc.

```
a, b, c = zip(*(map(int, line.split()) for line in f if line.strip()))
```

Essentially, `zip` converts a bunch of iterators that produce "rows" into a single iterator that produces the "columns". A split up version would look like:

```
rows = (map(int, line.split()) for line in f if line.strip())
columns = zip(*rows)
a, b, c = columns
```

If you want the result to be `list`, not `tuple`, you can further wrap it to:

```
a, b, c = map(list, zip(*(map(int, line.split()) for line in f if line.strip())))
```

though that's getting pretty dense at this point.

Comment: `a, b, c = map(list, zip(*(map(int, line.split()) for line in sys.stdin.read() if line.strip())))
print(a,b,c)` how to terminate the loop here after reading n lines?

Comment: @ChiragDamania: One, don't call `.read()` (that slurps the whole file as a single string). Two, use `itertools.islice` to pull `n` lines, replacing `sys.stdin.read()` with `itertools.islice(sys.stdin, n)`.